# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout error

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, android-constraintlayout

The error says that I need to validate the android:layout_height/width in my code and that it doesn't have the required element of both android:layout_height/width. New to java so any help would be appreciated.

My MainActivity code is this:

```
    package com.example.name.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

My activity_main.xml code is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:context="com.example.name.myapplication.MainActivity">
       <TableLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/table_main"
           android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:stretchColumns="1">

           <TableRow>
               <TextView
                   android:layout_column="1"
                   android:text="@string/name"
                   android:padding="3dip" />

               <TextView
                   android:text="@string/address"
                   android:padding="3dip" />

               <TextView
                   android:text="@string/phone"
                   android:gravity="right"
                   android:padding="3dip" />

               <TextView
                   android:text="@string/fax"
                   android:gravity="right"
                   android:padding="3dip"
                   android:layout_height="45dp"/>

          </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't added any height or width constraints to your Constraint Layout. Therefore, your application has no idea how high or wide to make this layout.

Try adding these under your Constraint Layout:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

So your code will look like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.name.myapplication.MainActivity">
```